# Insert nodes of a binary tree into a linked list (C++)

Tags: c++, linked-list, binary-tree

I have five files: source.cpp, orderedLinkedList.h which inherits from linkedList.h, and binarySearchTree.h which inherits from binaryTree.h. I'm trying to insert a node from a binary tree into a linked list using a function called createList which takes an orderedLinkedList object as an argument and is a member of bSearchTreeType.

```
//These two functions are in binarySearchTree.h
template <class elemType>
void bSearchTreeType<elemType>::createList(orderedLinkedList<elemType> list)
{
    inorderInsert(root, list);
}

template <class elemType>
void bSearchTreeType<elemType>::inorderInsert
(bNodeType<elemType> *p, orderedLinkedList<elemType> list)
{
    if (p != nullptr)
    {
        inorderInsert(p->lLink, list);
        list.insertLast(p->info);
        inorderInsert(p->rLink, list);
    }
}
________________________________________________________
//Insert functions from orderedLinkedList.h
template <class Type>
void orderedLinkedList<Type>::insert(const Type& newItem)
{

    nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list
    nodeType<Type> *trailCurrent = NULL; //pointer just before current
    nodeType<Type> *newNode; //pointer to create a node
    bool found;
    newNode = new nodeType<Type>; //create the node
    newNode->info = newItem; //store newItem in the node
    newNode->link = nullptr; //set the link field of the node
    //to nullptr
    if (first == nullptr) //Case 1
    {
        first = newNode;
        last = newNode;
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        current = first;
        found = false;
        while (current != nullptr && !found) //search the list
            if (current->info >= newItem)
                found = true;
            else
            {
                trailCurrent = current;
                current = current->link;
            }
        if (current == first) //Case 2
        {
            newNode->link = first;
            first = newNode;
            count++;
        }
        else //Case 3
        {
            trailCurrent->link = newNode;
            newNode->link = current;
            if (current == nullptr)
                last = newNode;
            count++;
        }
    }//end else
}//end insert
template <class Type>
void orderedLinkedList<Type>::insertLast(const Type& newItem)
{
    insert(newItem);
}//end insertLast
```

The problem is that when I call insertLast, which is a member function of orderedLinkedList, it seems that nothing happens. My code compiles and everything else works as intended. Is this an inheritance issue? How do I make it so that insertLast works when used in the binarySearchTree file?

Comment: You're passing `list` by value in all those functions, so you make a copy of it, change the copy, then throw it away.

Comment: Ampersands are your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already pointed out, your methods `createList` and `inorderInsert` take the list by value, so they copy it, change the copy and then do nothing with the copy. So it gets destroyed and all the work is wasted. Your point that it also does not work in `createList` directly is moot, since `createList` also takes the list by value, so it will be inserted in the local list (and you can check this with some output directly in this method) but it won't affect the list with which you call this method.

You should either pass the list by reference as seen here:

```cpp
template <class elemType>
void bSearchTreeType<elemType>::createList(orderedLinkedList<elemType> &list)
{
    inorderInsert(root, list);
}

template <class elemType>
void bSearchTreeType<elemType>::inorderInsert
(bNodeType<elemType> *p, orderedLinkedList<elemType> &list)
{
   //...
}
```

(note the `&`), or create the list in the method and return it, as seen here:

```cpp
template <class elemType>
orderedLinkedList<elemType> bSearchTreeType<elemType>::createList()
{
    return inorderInsert(root);
}

template <class elemType>
orderedLinkedList<elemType> bSearchTreeType<elemType>::inorderInsert
(bNodeType<elemType> *p, orderedLinkedList<elemType> list, orderedLinkedList<elemType> list = {}) // Default parameter, so we don't have to do it in createList
{
    orderedLinkedList<elemType> list
    if (p != nullptr)
    {
        list = inorderInsert(p->lLink, list);
        list.insertLast(p->info);
        list = inorderInsert(p->rLink, list);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Personally, I would prefer a hybrid solution, where `createList` generates it and returns it and `inorderInsert` takes it by reference and modifies it.